# Vue v-file-input with camera capture

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

Is there a way in vue to get a file input from a camera, analogous to the plain html method:

```html
<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera" />
```

I'm looking for something like this:

```html
<v-file-input capture="camera" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

based on [w3 docs](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-media-capture/#dom-htmlinputelement-capture) you should use `capture` with `user` as value and add `accept` attribute :

```
 <v-file-input
      label="File input"
      outlined
      dense
      capture="user"
      accept="image/*"
    ></v-file-input>
```

Comment: In my specific case I had to use `capture="environment"` to use the front camera. Options include `user`, `environment`, `left`, and `right`. See [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/mediacapture-streams/#constrainable-properties) for more details.

Comment: how to capture multiple ? I've already added the multiple prop but it only allows one capture.